# is there any way in mysql to rollup and merge columns at the same time?

Tags: mysql

if there is a table of the format

| continent | country | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 10 |
| A | Y | 20 |
| B | Z | 30 |

the output should look like

| region | val |
| --- | --- |
| A | 30 |
| B | 30 |
| X | 10 |
| Y | 20 |
| Z | 30 |

Comment: That's not what `ROLLUP` in SQL does.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for UNION ALL.

```sql
SELECT country region, SUM(val) val
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY country
UNION ALL
SELECT continent region, SUM(val) val
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY continent
```

It does two separate aggregating queries, then concantenates their results. UNION ALL is a little cheaper than UNION because UNION removes duplicate rows, which you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    continent AS region,
    SUM( val ) AS val
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    continent

UNION

SELECT
    country AS region,
    val
FROM
    table
```